# Atualizar linha Datatable após evento CellEdit primefaces!

Tags: java, primefaces, datatable

Estou atualizando uma célula do datatable, ele possui 3 colunas, descrição, preço atual e preço antigo.
Consigo chamar normalmente o bean para realizar a alteração e salvar no bd. Porém não consigo atualizar o registro no datatable. não consigo atualizar a "row" da célula q estou enviando. Tentei através do , tentei através do RequestContext, porém não tive sucesso em ambos.

```
    <p:dataTable var="tabela" 
value="#{cad012Bean.listaCptTerceirizadaServico}" 
editable="true" editMode="cell"
id="listadeServicosTerceirizados"
emptyMessage="Sem registro para mostrar"
widgetVar="#{widgetVar}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">

    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{cad012Bean.onCellEdit}" update=":listadeServicosTerceirizados" />

    <p:column headerText="Serviço" filterBy="#{tabela.descricao}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{tabela.descricao}"  />
    </p:column> 
    <p:column headerText="Valor atual"> 
        <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{tabela.valor}" id="e"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{tabela.valor}"/>
                    </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
     </p:column> 
     <p:column headerText="Valor anterior">
        <h:outputText value="#{cad012Bean.retornaValorAnterior(rowIndex)}" />
     </p:column> 
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Você quer atualizar `<p:inputText value="#{tabela.valor}"/>`?

Comment: Não, quero atualizar o valor anterior. o metodo retornaValorAnterior(rowIndex)  que ele tem no value, ele pega a lista e pega o ultimo valor. A lista no back ta sendo atualizada, porém no front não.

Comment: Poste o seu form inteiro por favor.